# How show a table in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: bootstrap-4

I wanna show a table in bootstrap tooltip.

```html
<i class="fas fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" 
    title="<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>"></i>
```

My javascript code is:

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

What i did wrong here? Please give me solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your HTML code.
For this tooltip work properly, you need to call the required libraries in the appropriate order.

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<i class="fas fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" 
    title="<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>">Text</i>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I already added this. My other tooltip works perfectly. But this one not working.

Comment: Edited the answer. No problem with your HTML. Check the snippet to see if you did it right.